# ARC causing me pain

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I realize there are tutorials, but they never seem to go deep enough.

Right now, I have an app that allows invoicing. However, due to the dynamic nature of the data types, I keep this as a sharedObject in a main user class, not a class on its own. Each invoice is contained in an `NSMutableDictionary`, which can contain as many or as little member objects as possible. There are so many different types of invoices that we found it best to do this way.

Problem we have now, is when one invoice is done, and another created, the UI for those items seem to retain the previous invoice values, even though at the end of the invoice, I set the `NSMutableDictionary` to nil.

Basic process: through several view controllers in varying sequence, I set the value input into NSTextFields as NSStrings as values for keys in the main `NSMutableDictionary`, and move to the next appropriate screen.

These `NSTextFields` are declared as non atomic, strong.

Their values are set with

```
[myNSMutableDictionary addObject:textField.value forKey:@"thisValue"];
```

Because ARC, nothing is released explicitly, and I've made careful to not alloc and init anything.

Each screen `onDidShow` assigns text fields with its respective value in the `NSMutableDictionary`.

What I expect, is during the current invoice no text fields will contain old values, and on successfully submitting the invoice to the cloud service, the entire invoice is blanked out. Never stored in device (except when backgrounded).

What I get, as a result of setting the `NSMutableDictionary` to nil, is that screens seem to retain either their previous values, sometimes nil, but most often the value of the previous invoice.

Is there a convenience method to set all members to nil, or should I:

Declare the `NSMutableDictionary` as nonatomic, strong in my sharedManager, Alloc / Init the invoice `NSMutableDictionary` when I want a new one, but declare all `IBOutlets` as nonatomic, weak (so assigns in one direction or the other do not retain), and ensure if I do need to alloc an object to be added to the `NSMutableDictionary`, that they are declared somehow also as weak? It may occur that eg, I need to store an NSArray in the `NSMutableDictionary`, I

```
[myArray alloc] initWithObjects:value1, value2, nil]];
```

What I'm saying, is even though I set the invoice as nil, value1 and value2 seem zombied, but reassigned after a second pass-through the code.

---

**Sample code:**
in User.h, I have a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *currentInvoice;
```

in User.m, I instantiate during an 'init' method:

```
currentInvoice = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
```

When a new invoice is created (in InvoiceViewController.m):

```
User *userInfo = [User sharedManager];
userInfo.currentInvoice = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   _clientId, @"clientId",
                                   _clientType, @"clientType",
                                   _txtClientName.text, @"clientName",
                                   keyContactName, @"keyContactId",
                                   orderTypeNum, @"orderType",
                                   _keyContact.text, @"keyContact",
                                   _problemDescription.text, @"problemDescription",
                                   _dateOfService.text, @"startDate",
                                   _startTime.text, @"startTime",
                                   _endTime.text, @"endTime", nil];
```

(Btw, I think i solved my problem, as i never re-instantiate a new userInfo.currentInvoice, just copy over the old one, it's members not mentioned here are likely still in tact)

Elsewhere in InvoiceViewController.m, a method that essentially cancel's the invoice process:

```
- (IBAction) dismissViewController:(id)action: {
     User *userInfo = [User sharedManager];
     userInfo.currentInvoice = nil;
}
```

In InvoiceStepTwoViewController.m, another controller with other aspects of the same invoice:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *clientName; // in the .h, of course
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView; // in .h, used to capture data

- (void)viewDidAppear {
    User *userInfo = [User sharedManager];        
    _clientName.text = [userInfo.currentInvoice objectForKey:@"clientName"];
}
```

After a bit of changing and capturing values,

```
- (IBAction)finishStepTwo:(id)sender {
    [userInfo.currentInvoice addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_textView.text, @"nerdspeak", nil]]; // so that NSMutableDictionary.currentInvoice objectForKey:@"nerdspeak" will contain _textView.text's value... but will currentInvoice own this object now? Will invoiceStepTwoViewController retain this as long as is possible?
}
```

My question; are my viewControllers (there are many more) unintentionally retaining values due to @property (strong, nonatomic) and never letting go (because viewDidUnload never seems to be called), and that's why data doesn't seem to reinit, OR is it because when I do add a new invoice, I don't actually reinstantiate, but just copy over other values?

Comment: Can you show some code? It's tough to read walls of text like this.

Comment: Are you sure your issue is actually related to ARC? Perhaps you just need to reload the data on every screen if it is changed. Perhaps use NSNotificationCenter to send a notification to all visible screens that it needs updating whenever an invoice is changed / removed, etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "and I've made careful to not alloc and init anything"? You still need to alloc and init your objects with ARC.

Comment: It is ARC in that my objects stay referenced longer than if I were to manually release when no longer required. But, I've made assumptions over the NSMutableArray life cycle rather than making provisions to control life cycle events. So I've added methods in User.h where the currentInvoice is a shareManager instance variable, rather than reinstantiate elsewhere and risk that controller become last owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without much code to go from it looks like this doesn't have anything to do with ARC, therefore modifying the `@property` declarations (i.e. `strong` to `weak`) will have no affect.

It sounds like your "datasource" from which your UI is populated is an `NSMutableDictionary`. And it sounds like you're setting this dictionary to `nil` and then assigning it to a new `NSMutableDictionary` that contains a new invoice's data. This sounds solid.

However changing the value of the `NSMutableDictionary` will not automatically modify the values of your UI elements (e.g. `self.textLabel.text`). You will need a method that functions similarly to `UITableView`'s `reloadData` method in that you invoke it when you update your datasource (i.e. your dictionary) and it manages updating the UI accordingly.

So, doesn't seem like this is ARC related, but related to the natural behavior of objects like `UILabel`.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Marked as answer, because I realize I'm not fully setting this as nil, and reassigning a new NSMutableDictionary. I've added methods in User.h to initInvoice, deleteInvoice, and restoreInvoiceFromPlist so that only User.m is responsible for managing the currentInvoice object's life cycle and not any other viewController. This should alleviate any self-imposed confusion over ownership.